# Is it bad practice to set the transition property directly inside a pseudo class?

Tags: css, hover, transition

Which is the best practice and **why**? Is there a difference between these two cases?

**1.**

```
a {
    transition: color 325ms;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

**2.**

```
a:hover {
    transition: color 325ms;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bad practice, it depends. If you put `transition` in a pseudo `class`, than the transition will only happen when you are getting your mouse on the element, whereas if you put the `transition` on the base selector itself, which will animate on the element on mouse over and on mouse out.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fvksfg16/) (Only if you declare `transition` on hover)

Vs

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/fvksfg16/1/) (`transition` on mouseover + mouseout)